# Need of Encryption/Decryption of REST API request/response?

Tags: rest, security, encryption, https, network-security

In what situations is it needed to **encrypt** the REST API **HttpRequest** at the client-side before sending it to the server and to encrypt the **HttpResponse** at the server before sending it to the client-side?

I read that **HTTPS** encrypts the data when data is in transit, so do we really need an extra layer of encryption on our own?

One difference I could notice that using additional encryption I will not be able to see the data in the original form in the **Network** tab of the browser. What is the significance of this from a security perspective?

Please consider the question for both mobile and web platforms.

Comment: HTTPS is designed by security experts, it is the preferred solution. Better use HTTPS and if you need additional security perform HTTPS certificate pinning to prevent interception.

Comment: @Robert We are already using HTTPS. Is there any significance of encrypting API requests and responses?

Comment: That depends on the security requirements and the attack scenario.